# C++ Check if mount path is still mounted

Tags: c++, linux, mount

I have the details of the mount path (specifically mount prefix) as obtained using `getmntent`
in the structure as defined below:

```
struct mntent {
    char *mnt_fsname;   /* name of mounted file system */
    char *mnt_dir;      /* file system path prefix */
    char *mnt_type;     /* mount type (see mntent.h) */
    char *mnt_opts;     /* mount options (see mntent.h) */
    int   mnt_freq;     /* dump frequency in days */
    int   mnt_passno;   /* pass number on parallel fsck */
};
```

Using `mnt_dir` I want to check if the mount path is still mounted after a while as it is possible that before some processing is done on it, it might have been unmounted.
What is the most efficient way to check if the path is still mounted?

Also Is there a way to get callback in case the path gets unmounted?

Comment: Sidenote: just keep the device busy so it cannot be unmounted?

Comment: That cannot be done, I have no control over the device

Comment: You can't open a file? :)

Comment: Not supposed to do anything with the device :(

Answer (score 2):

I'd say that the most efficient way is to cache `st_dev` and `st_ino` returned by `stat()` (although probably caching just `st_dev` should be enough).

If the volume gets unmounted, the mount point reverts to the empty subdirectory in the parent filesystem where the volume was originally mounted, and `stat()` will return a different device+inode, for the same file path.

As far as being notified, poke around the `inotify(7)` interface, paying attention to the `IN_UNMOUNT` event.

Comment: Is there any similar notification provided by `fanotify(7) ` as well?

Comment: By using `stat` I will need to keep checking if the `st_dev` has changed at periodic intervals correct?  I have a list of path to be checked for, in that case won't it become too much of overhead to keep checking?